# How to allow users to enter only text in short questions in Google Form

Tags: google-forms, regex

I want users to enter only text in short questions in a Google Form.
Like,  if I ask user his name then he is allowed to enter only text.
No digits or special characters.

Comment: What should the user do if his name is "George Windsor the 3rd"   or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

To allow users to **enter only text in short questions** you should use the `Response validation` option and as the regular expression use **`Matches`**

```
^[A-Za-z]+
```

To take it a step further you can use an expression for **`1st Capital letter(Upper case) and the rest ONLY lower case letters`**

```
^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+
```

[image]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.